# What is the proper Time Format in Nifi Processors?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am just getting started with NiFi, and want to use the GetFile Processor to retrieve files from a folder.

I want to set the Maximum File Age attribute to be 3 months, but I have no idea how I should format this. I have had no luck finding constructive information  online.

Given that the other time values are of format "number_of_seconds sec" I could write the 3 months in seconds format, but that's a large number and seems like there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That property accepts a wide variety of "time formats". The largest `TimeUnit` recognized by NiFi is `week`, so I would recommend trying something like `12 weeks` (Java only provides up to `day`, but NiFi extends this). Inside the `GetFile` code, this is validated and translated to milliseconds for the actual age comparison.

[Related documentation which describes time units](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#run-schedule), but is not made clear from the processor docs. I'll make a note to update that.

Comment: I think `90 days` would be more accurate in this case